# socketpair() does not seem to be working when iPhone goes to sleep mode

Tags: iphone

I am developing an iPhone application where I use socketpair() as a means of communications between different modules of the application. It works fine as long as the iPhone is active. Once it goes to sleep, after few minutes (say 10 mins) the data that arrives at one end of the socketpair does not seem to be delivered to the other end. Once I wake it up, then all the data arrives at once (seems like it was being accumulated at the other end).

Could you let me know how can I fix this? Shall I use pipe() instead of socketpair() ?

Thanks.

Comment: ok, this is not about socketpair. It is the sleep mode of iphone that is suspending its network connection

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is done to save power while the iPhone is in sleep mode.

You can disable auto sleeping while your app is running if you wish, using the [`idleTimerDisabled` property of the UIApplication](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html).